# Switching Layouts Based on Screen Size in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am building a web app using Gatsby that needs to load a separate layout built using mobile ui library in mobile browser and different layout with another ui library when opening in desktop browser.

How should I achieve this at the root (app) component level?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can experiment with [`wrapPageElement` in `gatsby-browser.js` and `gatsby-ssr.js`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#wrapPageElement), returning different layout based on browser height:

```
const React = require("react")
const Layout = ...
const MobileLayout = ...

exports.wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => {

   // a made up hook to detect browser size, implement your own
   const isMobile = useDetectMobile()

  return (
    isMobile 
      ? <MobileLayout {...props}>{element}</MobileLayout> 
      : <Layout {...props}>{element}</Layout>

  )
}
```

This get tricky though, because during server-side generation you'd need a default layout, which may (or may not?) lead to faulty behavior? I'm not sure.

A safe bet is to generate a mobile version & a desktop version for your app, then detect browser size / type in `gatsby-browser` & redirect accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right. When dealing with SSR, one needs to have default layout initially and that makes things complicated. Better to have layouts pre-generated and got redirected to on browser size detection. Thank a lot!

Comment: For anyone applying this solution for different layouts, just make sure to use `import`  and `const export wrapPageElement` instead of `require` and `exports.wrapPageElement` respectively to make it work correctly.

Comment: how to detect browser size and redirect it ?